# What are ~/.m2 and ~/.p2 folders and can I delete them?

Tags: eclipse, maven, p2

I know they are somehow linked to `Eclipse` and `.m2` is related to maven.

However, I never really used maven and I don't use it anymore, though I still use `Eclipse`, and these two folders `~/.p2` and `~./m2` are about 4Gb each and I'm wondering if I can simply delete them.

To clarify, my `~/.p2` folder looks like that:

```sh
cd ~/.p2
du -sh */
3.2M    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/
 48M    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/
 45M    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/
3.6G    pool/
```

I'm wondering if `pool/` folder needs to be that big or do I have relic/zoombie files there and how to find out about it?

For example, why do I have so many versions of `PyDev`?

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Apr  4  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_4.5.5.201603221110
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 May 11  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.0.0.201605051159
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Jun 22  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.1.1.201606162013
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Jun 28  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.1.2.201606231256
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Sep 16  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.2.0.201608171824
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Oct 26  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.3.0.201610121612
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Nov  1  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.3.1.201610311318
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Dec  8  2016 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.4.0.201611281236
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Jan 25  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.5.0.201701191708
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Mar 22  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.6.0.201703221358
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Apr 12  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.7.0.201704111357
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Jun 16  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.8.0.201706061859
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Aug 28  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_5.9.2.201708151115
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Sep 22  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.0.0.201709191431
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Nov  9  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.1.0.201711051306
drwxr-xr-x 6 alan staff 192 Nov 29  2017 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.2.0.201711281614
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Mar  1  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.3.1.201802272029
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Mar 23  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.3.2.201803171248
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 May 15  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Jul 12  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.4.3.201807050139
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Aug  9  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.4.4.201807281807
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Oct  2  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Nov  9  2018 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.0.3.201811082356
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Feb 12  2019 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Jul  1  2019 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Aug 31  2019 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924
drwxr-xr-x 7 alan staff 224 Nov  7  2019 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.4.0.201910251334
drwxr-xr-x 8 alan staff 256 Mar  9 10:20 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138
drwxr-xr-x 8 alan staff 256 Jun  6 13:49 /Users/alan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.6.0.202006041357
```

I also have files as old as 2012, which I'm quite sure I'm not using them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- **`.m2`** is your **local Maven repository**. It contains all ever downloaded Maven dependencies and Maven plugins. **You can delete this folder** (except maybe existing configuration/settings files, outside of the `repository` subfolder). If required Maven will recreate this folder and download everything: in Eclipse right-click a project and choose *Maven > Update Project...*, click *Select All* and hit *OK*
- **`.p2`** of this size contains **most of your Eclipse installation** (all plugins Eclipse is made up of) that you installed via the Eclipse Installer (in contrast to installing Eclipse via unpacking a ZIP or using a DMG file on macOS where the plugins are contained in the `plugins` subfolder). **Do not delete this folder**, otherwise you will not be able to start Eclipse anymore. To clean up this folder, run the Eclipse Installer, in the top right menu select *Bundles Pools...* (in Eclipse, the term *bundle* is a synonym for *plugin*) and in the *Bundles Pool Management* dialog run *Clear Cache...* and *Cleanup Agent...*

Comment: I've downloaded the _Eclipse Installer_, run it, _Bundles Pools are already selected. But I have Eclipse already installed and running fine, so I'm not sure how to get the _Bundles Pool Management_. The installer only offers me choices of Eclipse to install, which I don't want to do lest it will mess up my current one. Advanced mode doesn't show anything like that.

Comment: To the right of _Bundles Pools..._ there is a switch, but _Bundles Pools..._ itself is a menu item on which you can click to open the _Bundles Pool Management_ dialog.

Comment: Perfect, it really does the clean up. Now it shinked from 3.6 Gb to mearly 408 Mb.

Answer (score 1):

The .m2 folder holds Maven configuration files and a copy of every artifact you ever downloaded.  You can typically delete the .m2/repository folder if you need the disk space.

The .p2 folder is apparently for the Eclipse installer.  I usually use a ZIP distribution which does not fill up this.